# Spring data mongodb: Work with dates, date has 2 hours of difference

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've this document stored in mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : "cpd4-734fc2db-a5b0-4881-b5d7-bf85d894178d",
    "expiresAt" : ISODate("2018-10-10T00:00:00Z")
}
```

In order to get sure, all data is right, I've got first the document and I've log some data:

```
Reference ref = this.mongoTemplate.findById("cpd4-734fc2db-a5b0-4881-b5d7-bf85d894178d", Reference.class);
LOG.info(ref.getExpiresAt().toString());
LOG.info(Long.toString(ref.getExpiresAt().getTime()));
```

The result is:

```
Wed Oct 10 02:00:00 CEST 2018    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
1539129600000
```

As you can see when I get the object, `the expiresAt` field is `02:00:00` instead of `00:00:00`.

Value in database is `expiresAt` field is: `ISODate("2018-10-10T00:00:00Z")`

Any ideas or thoughts welcome for this issue!

Comment: In mongo the stored date is in Zulu Time, And in your code it prints in Central Eastern Summer Time which is two hours ahead of Zulu time.

Comment: to avoid this you can set your system timezone to UTC
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
 System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");

Answer (score 0):

This date is in Zulu time (note the 'Z' on the end):

```
ISODate("2018-10-10T00:00:00Z")
```

When you do this, specifically the call to `.toString()`, you are converting the date into a local date string in your time zone, which appears to be Zulu+2:

```
LOG.info(ref.getExpiresAt().toString());
```

I usually set my server's time zone to UTC/Zulu/GMT, in order to avoid any automatic timezone conversions happening like this.